# Fresh install of Apache Directory Studio in macOS fails to start a new LDAP server

Tags: ldap

I installed Apache Directory Studio version 2.0.0-M17 via this [official download link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCjG6.png). I launched the software from Launchpad and created a new LDAP server.

However, when I try to start the server, the status changes quickly from *Starting* to *Stopped*, and no logs are displayed. How can I debug the problem?

I tried to modify the `ApacheDirectoryStudio.ini` and uncommented the following lines to config the heap memory:

```
-Xms1g
-Xmx2g
```

I relaunched the Eclipse-based studio software, but the situation is the same.

Here are the `apacheds.log`:

```
[17:34:12] INFO [org.apache.directory.server.UberjarMain] - Starting the service.
[17:34:14] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[17:34:14] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.2.840.113556.1.4.841' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[17:34:14] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.9.1.2' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[17:34:14] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.2.840.113556.1.4.319' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[17:34:14] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.2.840.113556.1.4.528' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[17:34:14] WARN [org.apache.directory.server.core.DefaultDirectoryService] - You didn't change the admin password of directory service instance 'default'.  Please update the admin password as soon as possible to prevent a possible security breach.
[09:32:44] INFO [org.apache.directory.server.UberjarMain] - Starting the service.
[09:32:46] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[09:32:46] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.2.840.113556.1.4.841' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[09:32:46] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.9.1.2' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[09:32:46] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.2.840.113556.1.4.319' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[09:32:46] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.2.840.113556.1.4.528' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.server.core.DefaultDirectoryService] - You didn't change the admin password of directory service instance 'default'.  Please update the admin password as soon as possible to prevent a possible security breach.
```

Operating System: macOS 10.15.7

[image]

Comment: Encounterd the same problem on Windows 11, following.

Comment: I am using "ApacheDirectoryStudio-2.0.0.v20210717-M17-win32.win32.x86_64" with "OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_11.0.12_7" now I am able to start directory server from directory studio. Note: I am using embedded directory server in directory studio.

Comment: how do you find out it's related to JDK? Seems JDK is not the cause in my case...

Comment: because since years, this problem never occured to me so it could be related to some updated versions. Also while searching and reading I felt that this could be the issue. So I decided to try older versions of Java and OpenJDK, this is the first time I saw on directory studio page that they recommend to install OpenJDK. Before this I was installing Java and that was working fine for me. Now I didn't install Java just OpenJDK. I was getting the same exact logs as you are getting. try the same versions I have mentioned and let me know if they also works for you.

Comment: Mine is using `openjdk version "17" 2021-09-14`, maybe I should downgrade to your version & try.